# What's wrong with this query? Paths

Tags: mysql, path, sql-like

I'm trying to get info from a table using a browser path column in the table. This is what the query looks like:

```
select * from selwowscheduler sc
join browser b on sc.scheduledbrowser = b.browserid

where b.browserpath like '*iexplore C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe'
```

Thing is, this returns nothing. I can put `%iexplore.exe` instead of `*iexplore C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe` and that returns something (though more than I want).

I thought maybe it was the literals `\` so I replaced the `\` with `\\`, but that didn't work either (Still returns nothing).

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Thanks.

EDIT: I know `*` is not a wild card, it is part of what is on the path. We use it to initiate different browsers on different PCs.

Comment: If you don't paste the actual data from both tables it is difficult to tell.

Comment: did you try %iexplore.exe% ? or %*iexplore% ?

Comment: What happens if you just replace `*` with `%` in the original query?

Comment: @roymustang86 I did, and that, plus some other restrictions, is the only way I can get it. But I wanted to know why the above doesn't work. 
@Juhana I know `*` is not a wild card, it is not meant to be. It is part of what is on the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape a backslash like that `\\\\`. Try:

```
where b.browserpath like '%iexplore C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Internet Explorer\\\\iexplore.exe'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the the `Like` syntax what is the `*` supposed to be matching against because `*` is not a special character `%` means match any character 0 or more and `_` means match any one character.

Also if you cannot use like to accomplish what you need I would look into `Regexp` which uses regular expressions to match against and are usually more adaptable then simple `Like` comparisons

Comment: `*` is not supposed to match anything, it is part of the path.

Answer (score 0):

Well first off `*` is not a valid wildcard for [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html) as near as I can tell which is why the query returns nothing (it is looking for a path with '*' in it). My guess without knowing exactly what you are looking for is that some variant of the `%` wildcard would work. It can be in the middle of the string such as:

```
where b.browserpath like 'C:%iexplore'
```

This would return all paths on "C" that end in iexplore. This:

```
where b.browserpath like 'C:\Program Files%.exe'
```

returns the paths to anything on "C:\Program Files" that has an ending of ".exe" and so on.